# How to find Auto Scaling Group name from newly created stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, autoscaling

I have created a new stack using AWS CLI, which creates a bunch of stuff (ASG, ELB etc). Now from Stack Name I wanted to get the list of ASG created. How can I do that?

Describe stack does not give any idea what all got created. It just gives stack id and params.

Can I pass it on in Output section in CFT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [the `aws cloudformation describe-stack-resource` command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/describe-stack-resource.html). You will find the ASG's name in the response's `PhysicalResourceId` field.

Comment: This gives error as, as I need to pass --logical-resource-id.

Comment: Got it. I can pass it from CFT.